# Java Object with ArrayList<String> gets SERIALIZED as a single String rather than an Array containing one String

Tags: json, rest, serialization, spring-boot, deserialization

I have a spring boot application with the following Java Class

```
class Student{
    int id;
    ArrayList<String> subjectsTaken;
}
```

I make a REST call to another service where an instance of Student is passed as an entity(in the body) in the POST request. Every thing works fine when the subjectsTaken variable has multiple entries in it.

When there are multiple entries in the subjectsTaken variable, the body in the POST request is as follows

{"id":1,"subjectsTaken":["science","mathematics","history"]}

where subjectsTaken is an Array of String

but when there is only 1 entry in the subjectsTaken variable, the request body is as follows

{"id":1,"subjectsTaken":"science"}

where subjectsTaken is just a String(and not an Array with one String)

Due to this reason the Deserialization fails in the called REST service with the following error

Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token.

Appreciate any pointers on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution to the problem. You can set this property in your application.properties file of the called service where the deserialization is happening.

spring.jackson.deserialization.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY=true

This helped to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating an array even if its just one subject. And send this array to the rest controller.

{"id":1,"subjectsTaken":["science"]}